# Creating custom Selector (multi switch) / WPF C#

Tags: wpf, controls, selector

I want to create control that will look like [this](http://s6.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/04/bf89d3dfc7e79338a6bf8457de612b86.png). So I choose to derive it from Selector and place items on Canvas.
Here is the question: how should I code the placing of items? (maybe create wrapper class for items that will contain coordinates, or just always recieve coordinates from Canvas?)

P.S. Or you may just send me to already implemented similar control (unfortunately, I didn't find any).

Answer (score -1):

See this [`example`](http://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/a-knob-slider-control) for the beginning. In this example contains ControlTemplate for `Slider`.

Example:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="SliderControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SliderControl"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <my:ValueAngleConverter x:Key="valueAngleConverter"/>
        <my:ValueTextConverter x:Key="valueTextConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Slider Name="knob">
            <Slider.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Margin="5">
                            <Ellipse Fill="LightBlue" Width="300" Height="300" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                                     Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10" MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp"                                     
                                     MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove" />

                            <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="60" Height="60" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="120" />
                                <Canvas>
                                    <Line Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="5" 
                                          X1="150" Y1="150" X2="150" Y2="10"
                                          MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp" />

                                    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="20" 
                                             Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="0" 
                                             MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                             MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                        <Ellipse.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value" Converter="{StaticResource valueTextConverter}"/>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </Ellipse.ToolTip>
                                </Ellipse>

                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150">
                                        <RotateTransform.Angle>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource valueAngleConverter}">
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </RotateTransform.Angle>
                                    </RotateTransform>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Slider.Template>
        </Slider>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _isPressed = false;
    private Canvas _templateCanvas = null;

    private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Enable moving mouse to change the value.
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Disable moving mouse to change the value.
        _isPressed = false;
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            //Find the parent canvas.
            if (_templateCanvas == null)
            {
                _templateCanvas = MyHelper.FindParent<Canvas>(e.Source as Ellipse);
                if (_templateCanvas == null) return;
            }
            //Canculate the current rotation angle and set the value.
            const double RADIUS = 150;
            Point newPos = e.GetPosition(_templateCanvas);
            double angle = MyHelper.GetAngleR(newPos, RADIUS);
            knob.Value = (knob.Maximum - knob.Minimum) * angle / (2 * Math.PI);
        }
    }
}

//The converter used to convert the value to the rotation angle.
public class ValueAngleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double value = (double)values[0];
        double minimum = (double)values[1];
        double maximum = (double)values[2];

        return MyHelper.GetAngle(value, maximum, minimum);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, 
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

//Convert the value to text.
public class ValueTextConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double v = (double)value;
        return String.Format("{0:F2}", v);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class MyHelper
{
    //Get the parent of an item.
    public static T FindParent<T>(FrameworkElement current)
      where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        do
        {
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current) as FrameworkElement;
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
        }
        while (current != null);
        return null;
    }

    //Get the rotation angle from the value
    public static double GetAngle(double value, double maximum, double minimum)
    {
        double current = (value / (maximum - minimum)) * 360;
        if (current == 360)
            current = 359.999;

        return current;
    }

    //Get the rotation angle from the position of the mouse
    public static double GetAngleR(Point pos, double radius)
    {
        //Calculate out the distance(r) between the center and the position
        Point center = new Point(radius, radius);
        double xDiff = center.X - pos.X;
        double yDiff = center.Y - pos.Y;
        double r = Math.Sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);

        //Calculate the angle
        double angle = Math.Acos((center.Y - pos.Y) / r);
        Console.WriteLine("r:{0},y:{1},angle:{2}.", r, pos.Y, angle);
        if (pos.X < radius)
            angle = 2 * Math.PI - angle;            
        if (Double.IsNaN(angle))
            return 0.0;
        else
            return angle;
    }
}
```

Screen of sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, but you didn't get me. I want to create not slider, but items control (I mean there can be not only numbers, but also words/other controls)

Comment: Can you put the elements around the slider? Each element corresponds number. For example: if slider value number 1 - user choose the button 1, number 2 - Button 2, etc.